# Java regex for matching certain parts of JSON substrings

Tags: java, regex, json, string

I am trying to write a regex that looks for strings with the following pattern:

1. Begin with an opening bracket `{` followed by a double-quote `"`
2. Then allows for a string of 1+ alphanumeric characters `a-zA-Z0-9`
3. Then another double-quote `"` followed by a colon `:` and an opening brace `[`
4. Then allows for any string of 0+ alphanumeric characters `a-zA-Z0-9`

So some strings that **would** match the regex:

```
{"hello":[blah
{"hello":[
{"1":[
```

And some strings that would **not** match:

```
{hello:[blah
hello":[
{"2:[
```

So far, the best I've been able to come up with is:

```
String regex = "{\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\":\[[a-zA-Z0-9]*";
if(myString.matches(regex))
    // do something
```

But I know I'm way off base. Can any regex gurus help reel me in? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use a JSON parser?

Comment: If I am to believe the [online regex tester](http://rextester.com/tester/QVV7252) this should work, unless of course there is some `Java` specifics I'm missing.

Comment: Nikolay - I've already stripped out all whitespace prior to this code being executed. jlordo - good call on the parser, but it feels like its overkill for this simple use case, but I definitely would use a parser if it become more complex than this.

Comment: You have a compiler error (invalid escape sequence). See Ian Roberts' answer. In cases like this, always include the complete error message in your question. See the [stackoverflow question checklist](http://tinyurl.com/so-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String regex = "{\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\":\[[a-zA-Z0-9]*";
```

The problem here is that you need an extra backslash before the square bracket.  This is because you need the *regex* to contain `\[` in order to match a square bracket, which means the *string literal* needs to contain `\\[` to escape the backslash for the Java code parser.  Similarly, you may also need to escape the `{` in the regex as it is a metacharacter (for bounded repetition counts)

```
String regex = "\\{\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\":\\[[a-zA-Z0-9]*";
```